# Hide div after clicking on hyperlink which opens a page in iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have created a sharepoint webpart. Inside this webpart I generate some html. In this html I have a div with ID "Div1" with some information. Below this div I have an iframe which is initial hidden. And as last I have 2  hyperlinks which has as target the iframe. How can I make my html as follow:

- when I click on the hyperlink the iframe will be visible
- when I click on the hyperlink the div with ID "Div1" will be hidden
- when I click on the hyperlink the iframe will load the url in the hyperlink

HTML:

```
<div id="Div1"> some information </div>
<iframe id="myIframe" name="myIframe" style="display:none;" />
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="myIframe">Google</a><br/>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="myIframe">Yahoo</a>
```

maybe in jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

This code says:

1. "When I click a hyperlink (`<a>` tag):

   a. Show the element with ID "myIframe"

   b. Hide the element with ID "Div1".

Using the target attribute for your hyperlink tags will correctly target the iFrame.

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('#myIframe').show();
    $('#Div1').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/tLu5w7b2/

However, if this is all you need to do, loading an entire library is overkill. You can achieve the same result using vanilla JS...

```
var lnks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i=0; i<lnks.length; ++i){
        lnks[i].onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById('myIframe').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'none';
    };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/tLu5w7b2/1/

Comment: No problem. Note that it will affect **all** hyperlinks on your page, which probably isn't what you want. You can narrow it down by using an ID selector (`$('#id')`) or a Class selector (`$('.class')`). [jQuery: Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). It could be done with Vanilla JS as well (loading a whole library just for this is overkill...).. I'll update with a vanilla JS example. (You'll probably find that once you start using jQuery, you'll use it more and more though...!)